# How to reset root user password in Mysql

Tags: mysql, root, mysql-5.1

I forgot the **ROOT password in Mysql**, i don't have admin rights for that system, how can i reset it?? 
I tried most of the methods by searching Google for all i got **access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes/no)**. Please help me to reset that password. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should contact the admin of that system and ask for help with your forgotten password.

Comment: In the case this a local MySQL server like XAMPP. Try the default password that is if you haven't reset the password.

Comment: In the case this is a default install from XAMPP the password is nothing so just enter. The key question here is this an external or local mysql server.

Comment: It is local mysql server

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

- How to Reset the Root Password
- C.5.4.1.1. Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems
- C.5.4.1.2. Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems
- C.5.4.1.3. Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions

Good luck!